# Continue working from an anchor point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, anchor-point

I am trying to figure out, how I can continue drawing from an anchor point on a line on Adobe Illustrator.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Smart Guides switched on (View > Smart Guides).

Deselect the path, taking a note of roughly where the anchor is.

Select the Pen tool, and move it over the line until you find the "anchor" which will display in tiny green text, then begin drawing your line.

[image: Using Smart Guides to find anchor]